# Executemany with WHERE using list

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I´m trying to do something like this.

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE tableA SET Col1 ='S' WHERE Col2 = %s AND Col3= %s ", data [:][0], data [:][4])
```

Where "data" is a list. I need make an update for each line in my list (data). For each line I need look for Clo1 equal element 0 and Col2 equal elemente 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the list before passing it to `executemany`, extracting the elements you need, perhaps like this:

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE tableA SET Col1 ='S' WHERE Col2 = ? AND Col3= ? ",
    [(row[0], row[4]) for row in data])
```